# Adjuntar columnas en Excel con Python

Tags: python

estoy pasando los datos de un Excel a otro con Python pero cuando los paso lo que tengo en el Excel se me borra y solo queda lo que le pase, como pueda hacer para que los datos que ya tengo en el Excel no se eliminen.

Gracias.

```
import pandas as pd

archivo = 'archio_del_que_lee.xlsx'


df = pd.read_excel(archivo)


# Columnas que extrae del archivo
df1 = df[['nombre', 'apellido', 'edad']]


with pd.ExcelWriter('salida125.xlsx')as writer:

df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='salida8',index= False)
```

Comment: tus ultimas dos lineas estan identadas?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? Al leer la documentación de `ExcelEriter` se mencionan los argumentos necesarios para hacerlo

Comment: @LF tus ultimas dos líneas están identadas? Si

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que decirle que si el archivo existe `if_sheet_exists` lo superponga `overlay`, y también colocar en modo append `a`, por defecto está en `w`.

Por otra parte toca indicarle que los nuevos datos los coloque a partir de la columna x, con `startcol`, porque por defecto lo coloca a partir de la columna 0. Espero haber entendido tu duda y haberte ayudado.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('salida125.xlsx', mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay")as writer:

    df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='salida8',index= False,startcol=3)
```

Por acá dejo al documentación:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Por favor, dale el formato correcto a tu código, agregando triples tildes invertidas (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo.

Comment: @Maidagan por si llegas a leerlo: procura no editar código cuya identación sea crítica (en este caso Python). En todo caso, de hacerlo, en vez de agregar los cuatro espacios, utiliza el formato de tildes invertidas (```).